# For Each byref x in y - instead of byval

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'd like to update each element of a list, after running a function on it. At the moment I'm using a `for each` loop, but the changes aren't saved... is there a version where the 'each' is passed `byref` so that changes are preserved.

for example, at present:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}

    Debug.Write(letters(1))
    For Each letter As String In letters
        letter = "d"
    Next
    Debug.Write(letters(1))
End Sub
```

prints `bb` but I'd like it to print `bd`

Comment: Even if you could do it ByRef, strings are immutable. Meaning they can't change. Your only option is to loop by index.

Comment: OK, so `list(of String)` was a bad example - the real code uses a custom class, that is mutable. I take it from your wording though that the mutability wasn't really the main issue

Comment: Whatever the type is, it doesn't matter in this case. `For Each foo As T In myListOfT : foo = bar` Will only change the reference of `foo` not the actual element of the list. Instead, you need to do something like `For i = 0 To myListOfT.Count - 1 : myListOfT(i) = bar : Next`.

Comment: OK, so all the comments agree... but the only answer states the direct opposite!

Comment: Well, the answer is wrong! It would be right if you try to _make changes to the element_, not _change the reference_. In other words, this will work `For Each foo As T In myListOfT : foo.MyProperty = "Something"`. Compare that to the first example in my previous comment where a reference to a new object is being assigned as opposed to making changes to the existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example were to use a list of reference types, then it would work as written. Strings are immutable. The only way to change one is by creating a new one and pointing your reference to that.

Comment: OK, what basic construct would have been a better example to have used than Strings?

Comment: Having tested it, it seems to be true, and I'll be marking it as the correct answer unless my test code in my answer is leading to incorrect results?

Comment: @MartinKS No, your test is correct. And the answer here would be right if you're trying to _modify_ the object as opposed to _changing the reference_ which I thought you were trying to do. Read my comment above to understand the difference. Moreover, since you're now accessing the object by the index, both should work fine. But if you used `For Each`, changing the reference will **not** affect the element of the list.

Comment: Thanks, it seems choosing terrible "simplified" code has led to two equally valid answers, based on two very different sensible assumptions about what I actually wanted to do. Lesson learned, bad question.

Comment: I think your example was too simplified, but it wasn't too much of a leap to get to your intent. I am new to participating on SO, but I see that there is no such thing as being too pedantic when asking or answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my test script to not use a list of immutable Strings following the comment from @the_lotus and the below now behaves as expected:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lines As New List(Of clsDepLine)

    lines.Add(New clsDepLine)
    lines.Add(New clsDepLine)

    lines(0).Account_Manager = "A"

    Debug.Write(lines(0).Account_Manager)

    For Each line As clsDepLine In lines
        line.Account_Manager = "b"
    Next
    Debug.Write(lines(0).Account_Manager)
End Sub
```

outputs `Ab`

for reference, clsDepLine is defined:

```
Public Class clsDepLine

   Public Property Account_Manager As String
   [...]more properties[...]
End Class
```